# What could cause this kind of error when inserting into a collection view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout

I get a really disgusting error when inserting into a collection view. I use autolayout, and everything has been setup through interface builder.

Error is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qrbfz9vb0s5f2u/error.txt) as was too big to paste.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? What was the problem in your case?

Comment: How are your auto-layout constraints defined (and how many are there)?

Comment: Hi Wain, that's the thing - I haven't defined any constraints myself. There are many that I can see under 'constraints' in my various views that have been auto-generated. Not sure what information I can give you.

Comment: It looks kinda like you've done a lot of tinkering with an XIB and a lot of constraints have been generated and processing them is just too much. Try going through them and tidying up, or turn off constraints and use the old autoresizing rules instead.

Comment: This is definitely problem with large number of the constraints in autolayout.
I had similar problem, everything was ok, until I've done some small changes in view (everything in IB). 
You can simply solve this problem switching off autolayout.

Comment: Interesting... I never realised that autolayout was so fragile. Wouldn't expect a framework to eventually crash itself without any warnings.